# Is there a Facebook plugin which allows users to post comments from my website to our Facebook Fanpage?

Tags: facebook, comments

I want to allow users to write a question or comment on our website and then post it to our Facebook Fanpage.  Is there a plugin that enables this?

Essentially it means I can engage my website users to ask questions directly to the rest of our fans on Facebook without them needing to actually leave my website and go to our Facebook Fanpage.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no plugin that achieves this functionality as this overrides comment ownership by the user. The user must be able to control where they would like to post their comment.